# jQuery post data returns empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

**The logic:**

I'm making an *AJAX* request to a *PHP* file that returns me a list for a dependent select box. The query selects a list of values based on a numeric value passed by a select box each time it changes.

**The problem:**

Everything works fine until the value of the select box is 0. It comes as an empty list, but I know that the query returns at least one value. I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

**Code**

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#col').change(function(){
        var col = $(this).val();
        console.log(col);
        if(col){
            $.ajax({
                url:"../class/ajaxArmarios.php",
                method:"POST",                    
                data:{"col":col},
                success:function(data){
                $('#armario').html(data);
                console.log(data)
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['col']) && !empty($_POST['col'])){
        require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\portalFormacao\conn\conn.php';
        $col = $_POST['col'];
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT armario FROM gestao_armarios WHERE 
        (identifiant IS NULL OR identifiant='') AND coluna=:col");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':col' => $col
        ));
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $rows = $query->fetchAll();
            echo '<option>Selecione o armário</option>';
            foreach ($rows as $data) {
                echo '<option value="'.$data["armario"].'">'.$data["armario"].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Error</option>';
        }
    }
```

It's the first time that I'm using *AJAX*, I don't understand very well yet. Why my code "fails" when passing 0?

Comment: Numerical `0` in javascript is falsy.  My assumption would be your if is not allowing the ajax to happen.  You should check against blank string or something else.  Unless it is a string `0` and you've verified in your network console that the ajax request does happen?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the `0`. I think that's it, I'll test right now.

Comment: My bad, it passes the `if`, the `console.log(data)` shows up, but it's empty.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php  Looks like it's a php issue.  `empty()` considers '0' to be empty

Comment: Your if statement is not the issue, any select value is always a string and `"0"` is actually a truthy. Your issue lies within your PHP if statement where `empty` considers `"0"` to be an empty value. That being said, you don't need `empty` when you're checking `isset` – you can simply replace with `$_POST['col'] != ''`

Comment: That was it! It's working now